# Typescript: getTime is not function

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript for my function. I have two sets of data in the database, one is `date` and one is `time`. Both are expecting strings.

I made one `POST` request when the user chooses the date, and that time will be selected for the user. I made a helper function for that, when the delivery time will start, it means user selecting time is expired, in which case I show them an alert on the front-end that shows.

> "Your selected time expired!" .

I am trying to pass default date parameter like this `now = new Date()` in my function instead of use directly `new Date()`. When I console log `typeof now` it shows the parameter is function.

PS: I am still new in Typescript. It will be great learning for me if someone give me detail about my mistake.

**This is my function throws the error**

```ts
const isStartimeExpired = (
    date: string,
    time: string,
    now = new Date(),
) => {
    const [startTime] = time.split(' - ');
    const newDate = new Date(`${date}T${startTime}`);
        
    if (newDate.getTime() < now.getTime()) { // this throws an error that getTime() is not function 
        return true;
    } else if (isEmptyString(date) || isEmptyString(time)) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
};
```

**This one works**

```ts
const isStartimeExpired = (
    date: string,
    time: string,
) => {
    const [startTime] = time.split(' - ');
    const newDate = new Date(`${date}T${startTime}`);
    
    if (newDate.getTime() < new Date().getTime()) { // this one does not throw any error
        return true;
    } else if (isEmptyString(date) || isEmptyString(time)) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: How do you call `isStarttimeExpired` function?

Comment: I have delivery start and end time. when the delivery `start time` start then the function trigger.

Comment: I belive the problem is you're passing `now` parameter to the first function. And value of that parameter is not a `Date` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to type the parameter `now` into a date, else the type of the parameter is `any`.

```
const isStartimeExpired = (
    date: string,
    time: string,
    now: Date = new Date(),
) => {
    const [startTime] = time.split(' - ');
    const newDate = new Date(`${date}T${startTime}`);
        
    if (newDate.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
        return true;
    } else if (isEmptyString(date) || isEmptyString(time)) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
};
```